# Accessing files using Build Action: Content

Tags: c#, visual-studio-express

The way I've previously accessed content files is by setting them to "Copy always/if newer", then loading the file directly.

However, browsing the web, it seems there's another way to load it - That it's automatically included in the .exe/.dll. However, I've been unable to find out what the method is, to access said included content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `Embedded Resource`. This will cause it to be streamed into your assembly.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120420222449/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) is Microsoft's walk thru.

Comment: Ah; based on my reading, Build Action: Content had its own separate embedding. OTOH, what I was seeing was circumstantial evidence. Recently learned how to use embedded resources, so no problem. :)

Comment: Content meerly moves the files.

Comment: link broken :(. God damn link only answers